# When using Mailgun templates, can a text only part be added to the message, to overcome the triggered spamassasin MIME_HTML_ONLY?

Tags: mailgun, spam

When using Mailgun templates to send messages, spamassasin triggers a MIME_HTML_ONLY which costs around -2 spam score, because the messages are sent with no text only part. Is there a way to generate a text only part with emails created through templates?